# open url while the browser is closed and the button is not blocked in c ++

Tags: c++, linux

I try to collaborate with the editor of Video Cinelerra GG that works on Linux, the person who was at the head of the project died in a traffic accident. I do not know programming, very little, but now I am very stuck with nonsense, it is that from the batch render wizard I want to open a quick start guide. Use this code searching the net:

```
    //new help button
BatchRenderHelp::BatchRenderHelp(BatchRenderThread *thread, int x, int y)
 : BC_GenericButton(x, y, _("?"))
{
    this->thread = thread;
    set_tooltip(_("Open quick start guide"));
}

int BatchRenderHelp::handle_event()
{
    system("$CIN_BROWSER file://$CIN_DAT/doc/help_br_index.html");
    return 0;
}
```

and it works very well, but only when the web browser is already open, the problem is that if the browser is closed, it opens when pressing the '?' button. but this button remains blocked and together with the entire assistant, until I close the browser. Is there any way to fix this? I recognize that I am not a programmer and I do this to try to collaborate, since I am a user of this free editor, which is the best we have on Linux. THANK YOU VERY MUCH IN ADVANCE.

Answer (score 0):

I have already solved it, instead of using the program's own shell to open the browser if it is closed, I have used the xdg-open option, and with this the browser is opened and the shell is released. the line is like this:

```
system("xdg-open file://$CIN_DAT/doc/help_br_index.html");
```

And now it works perfect. Thanks to SatckOverflow for the space it offers us.